# RAID 1 detected as RAID 0 when one drive is missing

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

This is a repeat of the question on the superuser forum: https://superuser.com/questions/1404338/raid-1-badly-detected-as-raid-0-when-one-drive-is-missing

I'm hoping that someone here might have a better idea of what to do since this is an Ubuntu forum and this issue is affecting ubuntu installs.

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a virtualbox vm (issue also seen with KVM vm). I have created a software RAID 1 with two disks. When i remove one of the disks, the system incorrectly detects the RAID setup as RAID 0.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 1

              Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
              UUID : 08ad8f87:f1e25c0a:b8058a10:d1886a27
            Events : 72

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
```

The way to overcome this issue at the moment is to detect this with a bash script and run the following:

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

And after that it seems to be in the expected state where one disk is missing from the RAID 1 setup:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue May  7 11:11:05 2019
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 10475456 (9.99 GiB 10.73 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 10475456 (9.99 GiB 10.73 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Tue May  7 13:41:08 2019
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
              UUID : 08ad8f87:f1e25c0a:b8058a10:d1886a27
            Events : 39

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

As long as i haven't reassembled the RAID 1 with just one disk i can connect the missing disk back in and all starts up correctly. If i have reassembled the RAID 1 with the one disk, then i need to run:

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
```

And then the new disk will sync with the working RAID 1 disk and i will have a fully assembled RAID 1 array again.

So the problem is why does the RAID 1 with one disk get detected as RAID 0? Is there a configuration that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has suggested a good solution. It's basically to create a systemd service that will run at startup and ensure that madadm starts the RAID array. The command to start the array is:

```
/sbin/mdadm --manage --run /dev/md127
```

On a good raid array this will do nothing since it's already started. On a bad array this will start the raid before it is mounted.